# Need to Replace Colons and Forward Slashes in String with Nothing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

Here's my code:

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'my_function_name', 8, 3);
function my_function_name($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value)
{
   if($posted_field->id == 5)
   {
      $chbaa = strtolower($_POST['item_meta'][1]);
      $chbab = strtolower($_POST['item_meta'][2]);
      $chbac = strtolower($_POST['item_meta'][3]);
      $chbad = strtolower($_POST['item_meta'][4]);
      $_POST['item_meta'][5] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $chbaa) . preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $chbab) . preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $chbac) . preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $chbad);
   }
   return $errors;
}
```

This currently removes all spaces from the different fields and drops everything to lowercase, combining the four fields into one string. Fields 1 (`$chbaa`) and 4 (`$chbad`), however, include forward slashes and colons respectively. Field 1 is a date, so it's formatted 00/00/0000 and field 4 is the time, so it's formatted 00:00:00. I need to remove the two forward slashes and the two colons from the string, replaced with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I replace /\s+/ with /[^0-9]/ for fields 1 and 4, and that does the trick.